# Golang GUI fyne-io help set up?

Tags: go

I just can not configure the GUI [fyne-io](https://github.com/fyne-io/fyne). `go get fyne.io/fyne` gave an error

> package fyne.io/fyne: unrecognized import path "fyne.io/fyne" (https fetch: Get https://fyne.io/fyne?go-
>   get=1: dial tcp: lookup fyne.io: no such host)

It’s good that IDE from JetBrains installed it from import

`import (
    "fyne.io/fyne/widget"
    "fyne.io/fyne/app"
)`

Then at **go run** there was an error

> exec: “gcc”: executable file not found in %PATH%

Installation [TDM-GCC](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/download) helped solve the problem

And then I can not move.

```
package main

import (
    "fyne.io/fyne/widget"
    "fyne.io/fyne/app"
)

func main() {
    app := app.New()

    w := app.NewWindow("Hello")
    w.SetContent(widget.NewVBox(
        widget.NewLabel("Hello Fyne!"),
        widget.NewButton("Quit", func() {
            app.Quit()
        }),
    ))

    w.ShowAndRun()
}
```

After go run error

> 2019/03/26 13:51:11 Fyne error:  failed to initialise OpenGL
>
> 2019/03/26 13:51:12   Cause: glClientWaitSync
>
> 2019/03/26 13:51:12   At: C:/gopath/src/fyne.io/fyne/driver/gl/window.go:834
>
> panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
>
> [signal 0xc0000005 code=0x0 addr=0x10 pc=0x589c9d]

[gl](https://github.com/go-gl/gl) installed

Comment: We have identified an issue where some Windows computers will default to a graphics card that OpenGL support does not seem to be complete for. Is it possible that you have multiple graphics hardware as well (common in mid-high spec laptops)?

Answer (score 1):

From fyne documentation

```
By default Fyne uses the gl golang bindings which means you need a working OpenGL configuration. Debian/Ubuntu based systems may also need to install the libgl1-mesa-dev and xorg-dev packages.
```

What Is OpenGL?
OpenGL is a Graphics rendering API which is operating system independent, window system independent and has high-quality color images composed of geometric and image primitives.

```
OpenGL APIs can use following …

Gl
    OpenGL API implementation (http://www.opengl.org)
Glu
    OpenGL Utility
Glut – GLUT (OpenGL Utility Toolkit) – Glut is portable windowing API and it is not officially part of OpenGL.
    OpenGL Utility Toolkit (http://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/)
FLTK
    FlashLight ToolKit (http://www.fltk.org/)
GLEW…
```

Run the following commands to install OpenGL.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libglu1-mesa-dev freeglut3-dev mesa-common-dev
```

Comment: This helpful answer includes commands that are specific for Linux but the question is relating to Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Issue 1 looked like a temporary issue in your DNS lookup - the IDE resolved it shortly after.
Issue 2 well done on finding the solution.
Issue 3 you’d be best placed raising a bug on the GitHub tracker[1] - with details of your windows version and hardware so that it can be worked on with you.

1: https://github.com/fyne-io/fyne/issues

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your graphics driver is out of date. Some others have reported that by updating your drivers this issue has resolved itself.